How can I add a Youtube Playlist to `elfeed-tube` using `elfeed-org`?
I am using elfeed as my RSS reader, with elfeed-org to manage my indvidual feeds. Recently I found the elfeed-tube package, that allows a user to download the RSS feed of youtube channels as an RSS feed. It is a really excellent package.
One thing that I was having some difficult with, was downloading a Youtube playlist using
using elfeed-org. I tried to use the standard configuration for an elfeed-org link, but passing the playlist link as an org-link, like so.
[[https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxdnSsBqCrrF9KOQRB9ByfB0EUMwnLO9o][Lum Control]]

However this did not work, even though the docs for elfeed-tube indicate that the package is org-linkable. I was able to get regular channel feeds working just fine by finding the link in the channel_id of the page source.
If anyone has any suggestions, they would be appreciated.
